# Mudar propriedade somente leitura na própria classe

Tags: c#, .net, propriedade

Uma propriedade somente leitura implementa somente o acessor `get`. Mas e se eu quiser modificar essa propriedade na própria classe? Digamos

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    public string PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse { get; }

    private void UmMetodoPrivadoQualquer ( )
    {
        //Como eu mudo o valor da propriedade aqui?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use um setter privado:

```
public string PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse { get; private set; }
```

Dica encontrada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565075/how-to-set-the-value-of-a-read-only-property-with-generic-getters-and-setters

Teste: http://ideone.com/x3G1RY

Comment: Você por aqui? :)

Comment: Pois é, sumido. Mas estudando mais C# :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Saudades trabalhar com .NET haha :(

Comment: @Laerte Mesmo sem demanda de cliente, às vezes estudo C# pra desintoxicar do PHP :)

Answer (score 3):

Pode determinar que o `set`é privado, assim:

```
public class MinhaClasse {
    public string PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse { get; private set; }

    private void UmMetodoPrivadoQualquer ( ) => PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse = "texto aqui";
}
```

Um exemplo mais completo:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var x = new MinhaClasse();
        WriteLine(x.PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse);
        x.UmMetodoPublicoQualquer();
        WriteLine(x.PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse);
        x.UmMetodoPublico();
        WriteLine(x.PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse);
    }
}
public class MinhaClasse {
    //pode inicializar a propriedade se quiser
    public string PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse { get; private set; } = "Texto inicial";

    private void UmMetodoPrivadoQualquer() => PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse = "Outro texto";
    public void UmMetodoPublicoQualquer() => PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse = "Novo texto"; //pode alterar em método públicos também
    public void UmMetodoPublico() => UmMetodoPrivadoQualquer(); //o único jeito de chamar um método privado externamente é dentro de um público
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zD0khr). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bwmTMm). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Property/PrivateSet.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Aí o caminho é não usar *auto properties*:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    private string _propriedadeDeMinhaClasse;
    public string PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse 
    { 
        get { return _propriedadeDeMinhaClasse; } 
    }

    private void UmMetodoPrivadoQualquer ()
    {
        _propriedadeDeMinhaClasse = // valor
    }
}
```

Ou `private set;`, que é quase a mesma coisa:

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    public string PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse { get; private set; }

    private void UmMetodoPrivadoQualquer ()
    {
        PropriedadeDeMinhaClasse = // valor
    }
}
```